# Changing system time using /bin/date

Tags: linux, http, shell, date, apache2

I'm trying to change system time via a script.

Basically the command `date -s "<date>"` doesn't work since I run the command as user www-data. Although I edited `/etc/sudoers` file to give root privileges to the user www-data, I still can't change or set time.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please, do make sure you set up your 'sudoers' file so that www-data is only able to run 'date' with superuser privileges, and not any application.

Comment: Consider whether this is a good idea.  `ntpd` automatically maintains your system's clock.

Comment: ntpd is cool but user should change it manually in this case.

Answer (score 5):

After editing a /etc/sudoers, do a

```
 sudo date -s
```

command. This will do the actual date command from "Root" user.

Just edit of /etc/sudoers is not enough, because it will not give a root to user, but it will give a capability to became root from user using `sudo` utility.

Comment: Normally, `sudo` prompts for your password when you use it.  You can use the `NOPASSWD` tag to override this.

Comment: `www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`  changed like this but still don't work

Comment: thetux4, how do you start `date -s` exactly? Try to start `id` utility in the same way and post results of it.

Comment: I just set it as `/bin/date -s <somedate>`.   the result of id utility is `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)`

Comment: and what are the results of "sudo id" ?

Comment: it didnt return something, i guess asked password.

Answer (score 1):

type

```
sudo visudo
```

add the next command

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/date
```

or

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/timedatectl
```

now you can edit your time from the specific account without password like

```
sudo timedatectl set-time <datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also should note that line

```
Default requiretty
```

should becommented in *sudoers* file. Otherwise you will get a message to STDERR, saying

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

when trying to invoke the script from outer world.

This was a problem in my case.